# What is the square root of "$i$"?

Tags: complex-numbers

Where $i$ is the square root of negative one. 
And is there a generalization of the $n$th root of $i$?
Also how would this look graphically on the real number axis?
Thanks

Comment: Have you heard of de Moivre's theorem, or Euler's formula?

Comment: There's no such thing as *the* square roots of non-real numbers. Read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/775877/55235) answer to see how to get all the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of any complex number, for all natural number $n$.

Comment: *Which* square root of $i$? There are two, both of which are non-real, and (unlike nonnegative real numbers) there is no obvious choice for "the" square root most complex numbers.

Comment: I've answered this before here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348934/taking-the-square-root-of-an-imaginary-number, I hope you check out my answer as I think it's what your looking for. It's the fourth answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\;w=a+bi\in\Bbb C\;$, then $\;z=x+yi\;$ fulfills $\;z^2=w\;$ iff

$$z^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi =a+bi\iff \begin{cases}x^2-y^2=a\\{}\\2xy=b\end{cases}$$

The above easy system has at least one solution and at most two different ones, and you'll have to be careful with the signs (pay attention in particular to the sign of $\;b\;$ .

Now, for your question only take $\;a=0\,,\,\,b=1\;$

Comment: Confirmed my suspicions from NS's answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question directly, one choice of $n$th root is as follows:

A square root of $i$ is given by
$$
z = \frac 1{\sqrt {2}} (1+i)
$$
Graphically, this is a $45^\circ$ ray of length $1$ from the origin of the complex plane.

An $n$th root of $i$ is given by
$$
z = \cos(\pi/(2n)) + i\sin(\pi/(2n))
$$
Graphically, this is a $(90/n)^\circ$ ray of length $1$ from the origin of the complex plane.

Comment: Beautiful, I really like how "i" has a real and imaginary part to it and that you can see it by simply graphing it!

Answer (score 3):

If you learned the trigonometric form of complex numbers, the problem is very easy to solve that way.

Just solve 
$$[R(\cos(\theta)+i\cos(\theta))]^2=i$$

Otherwise, let $z=a+bi$. Then
$$z^2=i \Leftrightarrow (a+bi)^2=i \Leftrightarrow a^2-b^2+2abi=i $$

This reduces to 
$$a^2=b^2$$
$$2ab=1$$

Which is easy to solve.

Comment: I haven't learned the trigonometric form. In your second way I'm assuming you let a^2 - b^2 equal the real part of i, which is clever. Thanks!

Comment: So is that `a = b = sqrt(0.5) (positive or negative)` ?

Comment: @paxdiablo $2ab=1$ implies that they both have the same sign. So yes, but both positive or both negative.

Answer (score 1):

According to de Moivre's formula, if we have complex number $z = r(cos\phi + isin\phi)$, then the equation $x = \sqrt[n]{z}$ has exactly $n$ different roots over a complex plane.
$$\sqrt[n]{z} = \sqrt[n]{r}(\cos \frac{\phi + 2\pi k}{n} + i\sin \frac{\phi + 2\pi k}{n}), k = 0, 1, ... n-1$$
So, for example
$$(\sqrt{i})_1 = \cos(\pi + \pi/4) + i\sin(\pi + \pi/4) = -\sqrt{2}/2-i\sqrt{2}/2$$
$$(\sqrt{i})_2 = \cos(2\pi + \pi/4) + i\sin(2\pi + \pi/4) = \sqrt{2}/2+i\sqrt{2}/2$$

These values obviosly can't be shown on real number axis but can be presented as dots on a complex plane: if $z = a + bi$, then you should take $a$ for $x$ coordinate and $b$ for $y$.
There's also an insteresting fact concerning graphical representation: roots of a complex number are always uniformly placed on a circle of radius $\sqrt[n]{r}$ and center in $(0,0)$ with $2\pi / n$ arc between every two adjacent roots.