# Complex and Imaginary Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

The square root of -1 is i.

**So what is the square root of i?**

Can we try $\sqrt i= a+bi$?

Or

$(\sqrt i)^2=(a+bi)^2$

Or perhaps another approach towards the solution?

Comment: $e^{i\pi/4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the square root of "$i$"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964467/what-is-the-square-root-of-i)

Comment: "*The surd of -1 is = i*" $\;-\;$ No, the square root***s*** of $-1$ are $\pm i$. "*Can we try i= a+bi?*" $\;-\;$ You must mean $i=(a+bi)^2$ instead. (*Note: the quotes are from the original question, which has been edited a few times since, not by the OP*.)

Comment: Also see my post for general case [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908074/quadratic-formula-in-complex-variables/1908263#1908263).

Answer (score -2):

You’re on the right track with your start, now that it’s been corrected.

Squaring gives

$i=a^2+2abi+b^2i^2$
$i=a^2+2abi-b^2$

You can then equate real and imaginary parts to get simultaneous equations for $a$ and $b$.