# Solve: $z^4 +2\sqrt3 +2i = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve: $z^4 +2\sqrt3 +2i = 0$

I'm already trying to solve this exercise for $20$ minutes, no luck. I got up to here:

$z^4 = -2i -2\sqrt3 = -2(\sqrt3 + i)$ but it's impossible to compute from here.

Also I tried: $z^8 = -2\sqrt3 -2i \rightarrow$ $z^8 = (4*3) -4 = 8 \rightarrow $ $z^8 = 8$

$z^8 = {{1}\over{8}}\text{Cis}(\pi)$ and from there to solve.

Comment: Write $-2i-2\sqrt 3$ in its polar form and use the first part of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766537/values-for-1i2-3/766543#766543) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$z^{4}=4\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\right)=4e^{-\frac{5}{6}\pi i}$$

Comment: Just solved it, thanks.

Comment: What's r? I know that it is $r^4 = 4$, so I keep it $r = ^{4}\sqrt4$?

Comment: And I keep that like that?