# Find square roots of $8 - 15i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the square roots of:
$8-15i.$

Could I get some working out to solve it?

Also what are different methods of doing it?

Comment: Take a look at trigonometrical form of a complex number and de Moivre's formula.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766537/values-for-1i2-3/766543#766543).

Comment: Very suggestively have $|8-15i|=\sqrt{8^2+15^2}=17$. No guarantees, but this suggests that we might try numbers with absolute value $\sqrt{17}$. The simplest of those are $4\pm i$. We have
$$(4+i)^2=16+8i+i^2=15+8i=i(8-15i).$$
Damn! So close! How could we cancel that extra $i$? Do you know how to find the square roots of $i$ with Moivre's formula?

Answer (score 4):

You might start with solving 
$$
(x + i y)^2 = 8 - 15 i
$$

component-wise (real part vs imaginary part), which leads to two equations in the two unknowns $x$ and $y$.

More general is using Euler's formula $e^{i \phi} = \cos \phi + i \sin \phi$, using polar coordinates $(r, \phi)$, $z = r e^{i \phi}$ with $z = x + i y$, $r = |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\tan \phi = y / x$.